# Returning head of linked list from a function

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, return

The function that I have created takes the heads of two linked lists of structs and uses them to update a member of the struct in the first linked list. Once my while loop has finished I wish to return the head of the struct 'a' however currently when I return it it has a value of NULL because of the while loop. How would I return the head of 'a' once it has been updated? I know that I have to use a temporary struct but how would I implement it?

```
struct artist *update_counts(struct artist *a, struct play *p)
{
    struct artist *tmp = a;
    int count = 0;
    while (a != NULL)
    {       
        while (a->artist_id == p->artist_id)
        {
            count += p->playcount;
            p = p->next;
        }
        a->playcount = count;   
        a = a->next;
        count = 0;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `return tmp;`...? By the way, `tmp` is *not* a "temporary struct".

Comment: C != C++, so it is usually best to tag only the language you are writing/compiling.

Comment: @immibis I can't just return tmp because it doesn't contain the updated linked list.

Comment: @George `tmp` doesn't contain a linked list at all; it contains a *pointer* to the head of the linked list.

Comment: You can use tmp instead of a in the while loop so that the pointer a is not changed.

Comment: There's no reason to return anything from this function, since the function doesn't add or remove items from the linked list. Also, you've got at least two bugs in the way you handle `p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, to visit the linked list, we can use a `head pointer` to keep its original linked list head like `head_p = ...inputed head node...`, and then use a `visitor pointer` to visit linked list like `visitor_p = visitor_p->next`. Here in your code, `tmp` is that `head pointer`.

```
struct artist *update_counts(struct artist *a, struct play *p)
{
    struct artist *tmp_head = a;//tmp is the head of inputed linked list a 
    int count = 0;
    while (a != NULL)
    {       
        while (a->artist_id == p->artist_id)
        {
            count += p->playcount;
            p = p->next;
        }
        a->playcount = count;   
        a = a->next;
        count = 0;
    }
    return tmp_head;//just return the head of a 
}
```